# basic groupby operations in Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am attempting to use Dask to handle a large file (50 gb). Typically, I would load it in memory and use Pandas. I want to groupby two columns "A", and "B", and whenever column "C" starts with a value, I want to repeat that value in that column for that particular group.

In pandas, I would do the following:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

What would be the equivalent in Dask? 
Also, I am a little bit lost as to how to structure problems in Dask as opposed to in Pandas,

thank you,

My progress so far:

First set index:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['A','B'])
```

Then groupby:

```
df1.groupby(['A','B']).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill').compute()
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears dask does not currently implement the `fillna` method for `GroupBy` objects. I've tried PRing it some time ago and gave up quite quickly.

Also, dask doesn't support the `method` parameter (as it isn't always trivial to implement with delayed algorithms).

A workaround for this could be using `fillna` before grouping, like so:

`df['C'] = df.fillna(0).groupby(['A','B'])['C']`

Although this wasn't tested.

You can find my (failed) attempt here: https://github.com/nirizr/dask/tree/groupy_fillna

Comment: Thank you Nirlzr. I want to fill the NAN subject to the value in each group, which typically differs between groups. Is your solution giving the same value to all the NANs despite them being in different groups?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you're correct. If that's your goal - will something similar to `df['C'] = df['C'].fillna(c_fill)` work?

Comment: Note that in my little example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048181/groupby-of-splitted-data-pandas if I read A as a dask dataframe, the following command works: A.groupby('ID')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill') )  However, in a larger dataset that I am interested in i get the following error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: T

Comment: @NirIzr - I know this is an old question, but can I ask why your attempt to implement fillna() didn't work? Is there some fundamental reason Dask doesn't support it?

Comment: Implementing that functionality on top of GroupBy was difficult.. since then GroupBy was rewritten.

Comment: @NirIzr It would be great if you could post the code snippet with the updated GroupBy method in dask! TIA -Dibya