# Groupby of splitted data (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine you have a large CSV file with several million rows that you process by chunks. **The file is too large to be loaded in memory**. What would be the best way to do groupby and apply a relatively "complex" function (like fillna), without letting the chunk size affect the results? I exemplify:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["A", "A", "C" ,"B", "A"], "value":[3,np.nan,4,5,np.nan]})

>>> A
  ID  value
0  A      2
1  A      3
2  C      4
3  B      5
4  A      6
```

if the chunk size is 2 and I groupby 'ID', then I would group the first two A's but leave aside the last A, which would affect the results for a non-straightforward apply function,

```
A.groupby('ID').fillna(method='fill')
```

the output would be:

```
   value
0    3.0
1    3.0
2    4.0
3    5.0
4    np.nan
```

Note that there is an np.nan in the last row where there should be a 3.

Thank you and I appreciate your help,

Comment: Can't you sort by ID before grouping?

Comment: Thanks Laurent. If i sort, I would load each chunk in memory separately and sort them individually. The problem would still be there if two same ID's that would belong to the same group are in different chunks, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a way to remember the last fill value.  I use the dictionary `memory` below

```
memory = {}

def fill(df):
    name = df.name
    df = df.copy()

    # fill from memory
    if name in memory.keys():
        df.iloc[0, :] = df.iloc[0, :].fillna(memory[name])

    # normal ffill
    df = df.fillna(method='ffill')

    # update memory
    memory.update({name: df.iloc[-1]})

    return df
```

---

```
memory

{}
```

---

```
A = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["A", "A", "C" ,"B", "A"], "value":[3,np.nan,4,5,np.nan]})
A
```

[image]

Now I'll `update` `A` for only the first 4 rows

```
A.update(A.iloc[:4].groupby('ID', group_keys=False).apply(fill))
A
```

[image]

Notice that only the value in row 1 was filled.  Row 4 was left alone.  However, let's look at `memory`

```
memory

{'A': ID       A
 value    3
 Name: 1, dtype: object, 'B': ID       B
 value    5
 Name: 3, dtype: object, 'C': ID       C
 value    4
 Name: 2, dtype: object}
```

Or more specifically `memory['A']`

```
ID       A
value    3
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

So let's now update `A` for only row 4

```
A.update(A.iloc[4:].groupby('ID', group_keys=False).apply(fill))
A
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks PiRSquared, the example that I show is to examplify the problem that I am running into. I would like the last row to be also a 3 instead of a nan

Comment: mutation inside a groupby is an anti pattern and should not be used

Comment: @Jeff I've significantly changed the post.  Would you still consider this an anti-pattern?

Comment: anti pattern by definition always. use dask for this

Comment: Thank you PiRSquared, I appreciate it, very helpful. I think I can incorporate this into my code. However, are you and Jeff suggesting using Dask would be preferable for this?

Comment: @dleal Jeff is.  I'm reading up on it now.  I'm inclined to trust his judgement on this.  This may have gotten you to the desired outcome but may be bad design.  Particularly if there is a more robust solution.

Comment: Maybe so, I'm also reading into it. I like your answer too though. I posted a similar question related to Dask here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901845/basic-groupby-operations-in-dask

Comment: What if I sort the Dataframe by "type" first using Dask, and also get the length of each group, then, i could specify the chunk size to be a list of lengths. So for example, for A length would be 3, and for B and C, it would be 1. Then, chunk size - [3,1,1]. I don't know if this is possible though

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to read in chunk-by-chunk and then write to disk after processing. I think @piRSquared's idea of "keeping memory of previously seen values" should work if the function you want to apply is ffill, though I'm sure @Jeff is right about Dask (which I'm not familiar).

I have made up a slightly longer file for testing. See below.

```
inputcsv = 'test.csv'
outputcsv = 'test.output.csv'
chunksize = 4

outfh = open(outputcsv, 'wb')
memory = None
len_memory = 0
#write file header to output file
pd.read_csv(inputcsv, nrows=0).to_csv(outfh, index=False)

for chunk in pd.read_csv(inputcsv, chunksize=chunksize):
    if memory is not None:
        len_memory = len(memory)
        #put memory in front of chunk
        chunk = pd.concat([memory.reset_index(), chunk], ignore_index=True)
        #ffill
    chunk['value'] = chunk.groupby('ID')['value'].fillna(method='ffill')
    #update memory
    memory = chunk.groupby('ID').last().dropna()
    #The first len_memory was from memory not input file. Get rid of them.
    chunk = chunk.iloc[len_memory:,:]
    chunk.to_csv(outfh, index=False, header=False)
outfh.close()

print pd.read_csv(inputcsv)
   ID  value
0   A    3.0
1   A    NaN
2   C    4.0
3   B    5.0
4   A    NaN
5   F    2.0
6   D    2.0
7   A    1.0
8   C    NaN
9   B    3.0
10  E    NaN
11  D    4.0
12  A    NaN
13  B    NaN
14  B    5.0
15  C    NaN
16  E    4.0
17  F    NaN
18  F    1.0
19  E    0.0

print pd.read_csv(outputcsv)
   ID  value
0   A    3.0
1   A    3.0
2   C    4.0
3   B    5.0
4   A    3.0
5   F    2.0
6   D    2.0
7   A    1.0
8   C    4.0
9   B    3.0
10  E    NaN
11  D    4.0
12  A    1.0
13  B    3.0
14  B    5.0
15  C    4.0
16  E    4.0
17  F    2.0
18  F    1.0
19  E    0.0
```